# Renaming columns after reshape in R

Tags: r

I used this line of code to transpose a dataset:

```
b2<-reshape(b1,timevar="Species",idvar="PointId",direction="wide")
```

and ended up with something like this:

```
Point Final$Count.tot.SPEC1 Final$Count.tot.SPEC2 ... FINAL$Count.tot.SPEC99
  1          1                       2            ...             0
  2          3                       0            ...             0
```

I want to rename all columns after "Point" by removing "Final$Count.tot." from the names, so that I have:

```
Point SPEC1 SPEC2 ... SPEC99
   1    1     2   ...   0
   2    3     0   ...   0
```

I have tried using this:

```
names(b2)<-gsub("Final$Count.tot.","",names(b2))
```

but it gets hung up on the non-characters.  I've searched Stack Overflow but have not found a solution that works for this case.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a special character in regular expressions (determines the line ending, see `?regexp`). You have to use `\\$` or set `fixed=TRUE` (see `?gsub`):

```
x <- c("Point", "Final$Count.tot.SPEC1", "Final$Count.tot.SPEC2")
gsub("Final$Count.tot.", "", x=x, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "Point" "SPEC1" "SPEC2"
```

Comment: That did it - thanks!  I did check out ?gsub but the help files are written in a manner that I often find difficult to interpret.  Here, it said: "Fixed: logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is. Overrides all conflicting arguments." and I was confused because I didn't realize that the default is to not match the pattern as is.